# XSLT - conditionally check element exist in Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like follows,

```
<doc>
  <a>
    <b></b>
  </a>
  <a></a>
  <a>
    <b></b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <c></c>
  </a>
  <a></a>
</doc>
```

what i need to do is if `<a>` has a `<b>` child (one or more) add `<end>` tag just before the end of the `<a>`node. if `<a>` has not `<b>` child do nothing.

so the result xml should be,

```
   <doc>
      <a>
        <b></b>
        <end></end>
      </a>
      <a></a>
      <a>
        <b></b>
        <b></b>
        <end></end>
      </a>
      <a>
        <c></c>
      </a>
      <a></a>
    </doc>
```

I cannot think about a way that how I should conditionally check in xpath to check if `<b>` child is existing or not in `<a>`.

I cannot use,

```
 <xsl:template match="a//b">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/> 
            <end></end>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

this adds `<end>` nodes to every `<b>` node.

Any suggestions how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `a[b]` to match `<a>` that has one or more *child* `<b>` :

```
<xsl:template match="a[b]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/> 
        <end></end>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or maybe `a[.//b]` if you rather meant to match `<a>` that has one or more *descendant* `<b>`.